# Dropbox returns incorrect content-type for HEAD requests

Tags: dropbox, head

When making a HEAD request to a Dropbox link that points to an image, it responds with "content-type: application/json".

I would expect image/jpeg

I have tried raw=1 and dl=1 - same thing.

What do I need to do to get the correct content-type?

`curl -LI https://www.dropbox.com/s/wprao85pg3fn3a6/zebra.jpeg\?raw\=1`

```
[...]
HTTP/2 200
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=60
content-disposition: inline; filename="zebra.jpeg"; filename*=UTF-8''zebra.jpeg
content-security-policy: report-uri https://www.dropbox.com/csp_log?policy_name=blockserver-usercontent ; sandbox allow-forms allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-popups
content-security-policy: form-action 'none' ; report-uri https://www.dropbox.com/csp_log?policy_name=blockserver-noscript ; script-src 'none'
etag: 1676988095219687d
pragma: public
referrer-policy: no-referrer
set-cookie:  uc_session=ER5xA37myw7JMYbzcEwQjAACNJEujM07QkC4Dt2o35vt46TYQIN1wUbB0GC2u4dx; Domain=dropboxusercontent.com; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-robots-tag: noindex, nofollow, noimageindex
x-server-response-time: 122
content-type: application/json
accept-encoding: identity,gzip
date: Tue, 21 Feb 2023 14:08:31 GMT
server: envoy
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-robots-tag: noindex, nofollow, noimageindex
content-length: 752557
x-dropbox-response-origin: far_remote
x-dropbox-request-id: 993f05793eaf413d8737dcac28a699b1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and is open with Dropbox engineering. I'll follow up here with any updates on this.